# ElasticSearch - [parsing_exception] [multi_match] malformed query

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, elasticsearch

I am getting this Error **[parsing_exception] [multi_match] malformed query** 
while a bulk search in ElasticSearch Database. I didn't find any error on the JSON object.
 
the Query on **is_processed": false** Records that contains name1 this fields ["NAME", "NICKNAME"] or Records that contains name2 this fields ["NAME", "NICKNAME"]

condition: **is_processed": false** AND **( name1 OR name2 in ["NAME", "NICKNAME"] )**

```
import * as elasticsearch from "elasticsearch";

const elasticClient = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: process.env.ELASTIC_HOST,
    log: 'error'
})

elasticClient.msearch({
            index: indexName,
            type: docType,
            body: payload
        })
```

I am sending this Payload. for searching

```
payload = '
           {}
           {
            "query": {
                      "bool": {
                               "must": [
                                        { "match": { "is_processed": false } },
                                        {
                                         "bool": {
                                                  "should":[
                                                             {
                                                              "multi_match": {
                                                                   "query": name1,
                                                                   "type": "cross_fields",
                                                                   "fields": ["NAME", "NICKNAME"],
                                                                   "minimum_should_match": "100%"
                                                                             }
                                                             },
                                                             {
                                                              "multi_match": {
                                                                   "query": name2,
                                                                   "type": "cross_fields",
                                                                   "fields": ["NAME", "NICKNAME"],
                                                                   "minimum_should_match": "100%"
                                                                             }
                                                             }
                                                           ]    
                                                  }
                                            }    
                                         ]
                               }
                       }
            }'
```

Error:

```
body:Object {error: Object, status: 400}
displayName:"BadRequest"
message:"[parsing_exception] [multi_match] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME], with { line=1 & col=121 }"
path:"/user/_msearch"
query:Object {type: "user"}
response:"{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[multi_match] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]","line":1,"col":121}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[multi_match] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]","line":1,"col":121},"status":400}"
stack:"Error: [parsing_exception] [multi_match] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME], with { line=1 & col=121 }
    at respond (/Users/apple/Desktop/Development/aml/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:349:15)
```

Comment: Please add the complete error.

Comment: ERROR : [parsing_exception] [multi_match] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME], with { line=1 & col=121 }

Comment: `payload = '
           {}
           {` this is not a valid. Are you sure you posted correct payload?

Comment: can anyone suggest query for this condition: is_processed": false AND ( name1 OR name2 in ["NAME", "NICKNAME"] )